# When does an object gets its memory?

Tags: c++, memory, gdb, stack-overflow

I have a function like this:

```
1  int main(){
2    int n,m; cin>>n>>m; // Only for illustration
3    vector<int> v[(int) 1e8] ;
4    // ...
5  }
```

I will have segmentation error because of stack overflow caused by line 3. Since, I was learning gdb I set a breakpoint on `main()` and at line 2.

I was expecting for the program not to allocate memory for the object before line 3, and line 1 and 2 should correctly run. Segmentation fault must occur after running line 3.
Alas! When ran the program it resulted in segmentation fault after line 1. I used `info locals` and it gave:

```
v= <error reading variable v (value requires 2400000000 bytes, which 
    is more than max-value-size)>
```

Which means program tried to allocate memory after entering main, but why is it the case?
I thought that scope of a variable is from the line it is declared because otherwise using it before declaration gives error.
I used this for compilation:

```
g++ -g temp.cpp -o temp -O0
```

**EDIT**:

1. This huge vector is intentional, because I was "learning" to use gdb. But then I encountered this conceptual error.
2. I restored the question to array of vectors from huge vector (1e10) as pointed in comments.

Comment: Do you want to allocate a single `vector` of 100,000,000 `int`s? Currently, you're attempting to allocate 100,000,000 `vector<int>`s

Comment: You are allocating an **array** of vectors. Space for this is allocated on entry. This is obviously blowing through the max stack segment size. It has not got to the point where it runs the constructor for vector which happens on line 3.

Comment: Try using `vector<int> v(100000000);` or see the `reserve` method.  Notice the difference between `()` and `[]`.  The latter means array.

Comment: Note:  if a variable is not used, the compiler may "optimize it away" and never perform any memory allocation.

Comment: @MartinYork, thanks for noticing the typo with brackets. I wanted to make large enough object to make stack overflow. Fixed it now.

Comment: @madhur4127 but unlike in your original example, in your "fixed" version you *aren't* making large enough object to make a stack overflow.

Comment: @user2079303, why? I get `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'` when I run this code. I have written some useless code after it to use the vector to prevent compiler from optimising it by removing it.

Comment: @madhur4127 `throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'` is completely different thing from `stack overflow`. Also, did you check after modification whether the exception is thrown at the line where your originally expected or not? I would expect that your results will differ.

Comment: I bet after modification the error message above is not completely irelavant. Also when stoping on line 2 you will not have thrown the bad_alloc. In my opinion the change above has completely voided the question (you should have asked a new one).

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  vector<int> v[(int) 1e8];
> ```
>
> I was expecting for the program not to do allocate memory for the object before line 3

This is an incorrect assumption.

The standard doesn't explicitly say *when* the storage of an automatic variable is acquired. It could be acquired at the beginning of the block-statement, although a compiler might hoist the allocation from an inner block into the outer. In fact, if the compiler expands the function call inline, the automatic variable might be allocated even before the execution reaches the function call expression.

> I thought that scope of a variable is from the line it is declared

That's correct. However, the *storage* of an object might exist longer than the lifetime of the object.

> Which means program tried to allocate memory after entering main, but why is it the case?

It's usually most efficient to allocate all stack objects of a function once at the start of the function. Stack allocation is nothing more than adding the size of the allocated objects to the stack pointer.

Comment: This is very helpful.

Comment: @OP I would note that space allocation of locals and life-time of variables are not the same thing. life-time is from construction to destruction. space allocation of locals may be done at any point before allocation (but usually on function entry).

Answer (score 0):

For creating variables on the stack is quite common ( but also not guaranteed as I know ) that all and everything is created in every block before any other statement is executed. And because the program can't reserve 1e8 vector instances on the heap, you program will fail by reserving the stack and this before any other statement can be executed.

The failure is not in creating the instances of the vector classes themselves, because the constructors will be called at line 3. But as said before, the program crashes before, because the stack is smaller as required.

BTW: Its allowed for the compiler to reorder all instructions as long as the result of execution is the same as written in your program.

Comment: but I specifically used -O0 flag to output code what I wrote without any optimisation from the compiler's side. From what I know `-O0` is literal translation of machine code from source code.

Comment: @madhur4127 The `-O0` does not guarantee no optimizations. Some optimizations are so trivial they happen automatically (coloring variables for register, re-use of memory for multiple variables etc). Reducing the optimization level is going to prevent some expensive optimizations but it does not provide a guarantee (unless you see that explicitly in your compiler documentation) of no optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

From one perspective, the correct answer would be to cite the text of the language standard about the lifetime of an object.

I think a lower-level explanation of what’s going on here would be more useful.  You’re allocating an array of a hundred million vectors.  (Are you *sure* you meant to do this, instead of one vector with a hundred million elements?)  Since this is inside `main`, the compiler could statically initialize them, but in this case, it’s attempting to allocate them off the stack.

How it does this will vary from target to target.  In most calling conventions, it does this by subtracting the number of bytes the stack frame and all local variables will need from the stack pointer, when the function is called.  That’s a lot more efficient than trying to set up a second frame pointer inside the function, which is why any local variables inside nested blocks will normally have their memory allocated when the function is called, too.

Even an empty vector needs a fair number of bytes—at minimum, a pointer and a `size_t`. So, eight or sixteen bytes each, depending on whether it’s a 32-bit or 64-bit program, times one hundred million, is almost a gigabyte or two.  In this case, that’s more memory than one function is allowed to gobble off the stack, so the program crashes immediately when it tries to set up the stack frame for `main()`.

This is separate from calling the constructor for the objects, which can have and depend on side-effects, and therefore aren’t allowed to be done as far in advance.  You could do these two steps separately yourself, by allocating a memory buffer and then calling placement `new` with that buffer as the address.